# VBA: Runtime Error 1004 Creating Pivot Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a pivotchart through VBA, but I am getting the error in the title. This is the first time I've tried to use the CreatePivotChart method, and I've tried every combination I can think of to try and force this to work. The below code is what runs before the error begins:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreatePiePivot()

Dim myWB As Workbook
Dim PieTool, Dashboard, Aggregate As Worksheet
Dim PivotCache As PivotCache
Dim PieTable As PivotTable
Dim PiePivot As Shape
Dim PivotRange, ChartSize As Range
Dim LastRow, LastCol As Long

'Define Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook

'Define worksheets
Set PieTool = myWB.Sheets("Tools2")
Set Dashboard = myWB.Sheets("Dashboard")
Set Aggregate = myWB.Sheets("Aggregate")

'Define last data points
LastRow = Aggregate.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Aggregate.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Define chart size
Set ChartSize = Dashboard.Range("B26:O50")

'Select first-last filled row&column for data
Set PivotRange = Aggregate.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Create pivot cache
Set PivotCache = myWB.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, PivotRange)

'Create pivot table
Set PieTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(PieTool.Range("A1"), "PieTable")

'Create pivot chart
Set PiePivot = PivotCache.CreatePivotChart(PieTool)
With PiePivot
    .XlChartType = xlPie
    .Left = ChartSize.Left
    .Top = ChartSize.Top
    .Width = ChartSize.Width
    .Height = ChartSize.Height
End With
```

The error pops here in step-through:

```
Set PiePivot = PivotCache.CreatePivotChart(PieTool)
```

I have also tried:

```
Set PiePivot = PivotCache.CreatePivotChart( _
    ChartLocation:=Dashboard, _
    XlChartType:=xlPie, _
    Left:=ChartSize.Left, _
    Top:=ChartSize.Top, _
    Width:=ChartSize.Width, _
    Height:=ChartSize.Height)
```

...but that threw the same error. I also tried taking out the "ChartLocation", "XlChartType", etc but the error persisted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the address of PivotRange what you expect it to be?

Comment: I set up a watch and it didn't return anything meaningful to me. However, I used the same idea for another sub and it worked appropriately, so I have good reason to think it is working as intended...?